# EC2 instance store volumes issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, storage

I have created an c3.2xlarge EC2 instance with the store volume specified as `2 x 80 GB (160 GB)`. But when I use `df -H` command, this is what i see, and there is not enough storage as specified.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.9G   62k  7.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1      8.4G  1.1G  7.2G  14% /
```

I need an EC2 instance to have at least 80 gigs of storage, which instance should I choose?

Comment: Did you launch it via the EC2 Management Console? If so, did you add the Instance Store volumes on the *Storage* page of the launch wizard?

Comment: The volumes are there, if you attached them at launch, as you should be able to confirm with `lsblk`.  You need to mount them and potentially format them first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the points in the comments.

The problem was; I used EC2 Management Console and didn't add the volumes when I created the cluster, I terminated that cluster, created a new one, on `Storage page` Added New Volume, chose the volume type as `Instance Store 0`.

```
[]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  75G  0 disk /media/ephemeral0
```

Now the 80 Gig volume is there.